# Comparar una variable con dos variables

Tags: javascript, nodejs

¿Existe alguna forma de comparar 2 variables con una?

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de simplificar el siguiente codigo:

```
if( variablePrincipal === valor1 || variablePrincipal === valor2 ){
    // Mi codigo
}
```

Comment: Alli no estas comparando 2 variables con una, de hecho nisiquiera estas comparando las 2 variables entre ellas, las estas comparando es entre dos valores hardcodeados y no una variable.

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que dice @Riven, estás usando una comparación estricta, las variables que vas a comparar no solo deben ser iguales semánticamente, sino del mismo tipo. Saludos

Comment: Corregido, lo siento, mi error

Comment: Creo que la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366643/comparar-una-variable-con-dos-variables/366647#366647) de @AlbertoSiurob es una de las posibilidades, no solo porque te permite comparar 2 valores, sino cuantos quepan en un tipo `Array`. El código es intuitivo y muy limpio.

Answer (score 1):

Esa es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero te puedo dar otra sugerencia basado en un arreglo

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  const possibilities = ['foo', 'bar'];
  const value = document.querySelector('input').value;
  if( possibilities.includes( value ) ) {
    console.log ('existe');
  } else {
    console.log('no existe');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<input>
<button>Buscar</button>
```

Comment: No entiendo el negativo la verdad, es lo mismo que hubiera implementado yo. Tienes mi +1.